# Xpages- Create New copy of saved document and open it without saving it

Tags: xpages

I have a document that I want to create a new version/copy of, so I am trying to do server-side javascript to

- Create a new document
- copy all items from the current document
- open the new document that I have created, without saving it

I am not able to open the newly created document, is this possible?

code I am using is:

```
var viewPanel=getComponent("viewPanel1");get the componet of viewPanel
var docIDArray=viewPanel.getSelectedIds(); get the array of document ids
for(i=0;i < docIDArray.length; i++){
    var docId=docIDArray[i];
    var doc=database.getDocumentByID(docId);
    var newDoc = database.CreateDocument
    doc.CopyAllItems (newDoc)
    var docUNID = newDoc.getUniversalID ()
    // need something here to open copied document
}
```

Comment: Since the new doc is not saved it doesnt have a universal ID.  Therefore, and ofcourse because it does not excist yet in the database, you cannot simply return the docunid als a unid for a notes document datasource.

Comment: When you say you want to open the document, do you mean you want to edit the document within an XPage? And do you want want to edit it within the same context (page) as the current open document, or are you looking to open it in a new XPage view ?

Comment: How do you want to open multiple documents? Every one in its own tab/window?

Answer (score 2):

You need to store the IDs in the session scope and then open the page and do the copy inside in one of the data source events:

```
var viewPanel=getComponent("viewPanel1");get the componet of viewPanel
var docIDArray=viewPanel.getSelectedIds(); get the array of document ids
sessionScope.alltheDocs = docIDArray;
```

then open the page where you want to have the new document. Inside that page you need to have a repeat control that matches the element count of alltheDocs. I probably would design it using a DojoTab container (one tab per document). Inside the repeat place a panel with a data source (or a custom control). Then in the queryNewDocument event you copy the fields using the variable name of your datasource.

Comment: Hi Jeremy. Yes I would like to open the new document in edit mode.As for I how I would like to have have it working would be from a view, select the document, click a button (create new version), which would create the a new copy (without having to save it) of the selected document and open it in edit mode

Comment: jarnail - What should happen when you select more that one document? You want to create one new document each?

Comment: The ideal solution (and to keep it simple) would be that client-side javascript would check that only one could be selected (I do not know if is going to be possible as I have not found any client-side javascript code regarding viewpannel). Having selected on document, I new copy would be created. Thanks for all the responses so far

Comment: Jarnail: The UI for selecting ONE element isn't a checkbox. It is a radio button. It confuses users if you go an "uncheck" boxes automatically (you could do that with some JS). Downside: you would need to create your own view control (e.g. by using the repeat control). BUT.... Do you need that 2 steps? (There are valid reasons, so it is a true question). You could construct a link that takes the unid as a parameter and read that in the page you open event of the empty xpage

Comment: Hi Stwissel: not sure what you mean or how 'read that in the page you open event of the empty xpage', aslo would this create a new document or open and existing document?

Comment: Construct the link as some page.xsp?olddoc=unid. Then use in queryneedocument getParam("olddoc") to get the I'd. Get the doc and do a copyallitems. Your xpage determines what doc you get (default is new doc unless you changed it)

Comment: Sorry for not replying for a few days. Have been way. First thank you for all your good comments. I have tried a different approach. I open existing the document as normal which is the modified. When I need to create a new version, I create a new copy of the document via the backend (reate doc, copy all items etc) and save it so a new copy is created, but return false in the save query event, so that the document opened is not save. ie. the original document is not changed. Is this a good solution?

Comment: No. Handover the UNID in a URL parameter (or a session variable) and open an empty form. In the QueryNew event check if there is a parameter. If it is there, then retrieve the original document and copy the items into the new document.

Comment: Hi I am still having a problem. I have tried the following in the queryNewDocument mode as suggested var exCon = facesContext.getExternalContext();var request = exCon.getRequest();var request = exCon.getRequest("docid");var oldDoc:NotesDocumentoldDoc = database.getDocumentByUNID(paramValue); The xpage datasource is document1, so what I am trying is oldDoc.copyAllItems(document1); but keep getting error on document. Not sure what is the correct parameter for the copyAllItems , so that the document opens with the values populated

Comment: The documentation gives it away. Document is a NotesDocumentDatasource and copyallitems needs a Notes document. Use document.getDocument.  you should be also able to just use params(), no need for request - unless you posted the field

Comment: 1: var unid = sessionScope.Unid ;
   2: var oldDoc:NotesDocument = database.getDocumentByUNID(unid);
   3: newDoc:NotesDocument = document.getDocument(true);
   4: oldDoc.copyAllItems(newDoc

Comment: var unid = sessionScope.Unid ; 
var oldDoc:NotesDocument = database.getDocumentByUNID(unid); 
newDoc:NotesDocument = document.getDocument(true); 
oldDoc.copyAllItems(newDoc), 
get error com.ibm.xsp.exception.EvaluationExceptionEx: Error while executing JavaScript action expression
Error while executing JavaScript action expression
Script interpreter error, line=3, col=33: [ReferenceError] 'document' not found
also tried  var unid = sessionScope.Unid ;
oldDoc.copyAllItems(newDoc) where company is the dataSource name, stll get same error company not found

Answer (score 0):

You could save these docs, then show them and add them to a deletion queue by marking a field on those docs. On save remove them from deletion queue as a work around possibly.

Answer (score 0):

1) Do not store Notes object to scope lasting longer than request.

2) If XPage has to inherit some values, it needs to read them from some source.

3) You can not inherit data from Notes document - according to (1) in memory object must not be stored in sessionScope (simplest way to pass objects between two pages), and you can not retrieve it by UNID/key (it is not saved, as requested).

So, (possibly) the only option is:

Make copy of source document - copy every field you are interested in into Map[String,Object]. Fields must be converted into "raw" objects String, Double, Date (java, not Notes) or their vectors for multivalues. You must not copy special (Notes objects) fields - names, dates, rich text! Names can be converted to strings, Dates can be retrieved as Java dates, rich text might be treated as MIME (String) (but with possible loss of formatting). I think you don't want to pass attachments.

In target XPage, define queryNewDocument event to lookup and initialize fields from this Map object. Delete the sessionScope object to prevent duplicates.

Comment: Actually you can inherit! In classic Domino you have &parentUNID= on creation and "inherit values from selected document". AFAIK works in XPages too. You might need to set "compute with form"

Comment: you are right. I thought Jarnail's request was to inherit from in memory document (that was his approach - prepare in memory documents and pass them to xpage). I have missed the detail, that he has documents selected in view - so he can easily inherit required fields via onNewDocument event or computeWithForm

Answer (score 0):

I needed very similar thing in my application. I have XPage with a source document opened in read mode. There is a button that creates a new document and set few values (using the source document). I wanted the XPage to open this new document in Edit mode after it was created. 
Note: I could not use redirect with URL parametr action as I needed to open it in a same XPage and preserve a view scope variables and beans.

Solution:

1. Add View Scope variables NewDocAction and documentId (on button click),
2. Partial refresh of XPage (on button)
3. Compute document data source using viewScope variable documentId
4. Check presence of View Scope variable NewDocAction (in onClienLoad event)

javascript code in the button:

```
var travelDoc = xpBean.createTravelDoc(requestDoc);
if (travelDoc != null){
    viewScope.put("content","travelForm"); //to render proper CC on XPage
    viewScope.put("documentId", travelDoc.getUniversalID());
    viewScope.put("NewDocAction", "ToEditMode");
}
```

javascript code in a onClientLoad event of a travelForm custom control:

```
if (viewScope.containsKey("NewDocAction") && viewScope.get("NewDocAction").equals("ToEditMode")){
    context.setDocumentMode("travelDoc","edit");
    viewScope.remove("NewDocAction");
}
```